How to redirect http errors response? - Custom Error Page
I am working on a web app with springboot, I want to be able to redirect the user when requesting a page that doesn't exist.
I've tried following this guide :https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-error-page
But it's not working as expected, the "/error" page works, but If I try to access a path that doesn't exists I get the usual message:
{"type":"about:blank","title":"Not Found","status":404,"detail":"No static resource randomURL.","instance":"/randomURL"}
I would like to get either my custom "404.html" or be redirected to the main page!

First, please confirm that you have added thymeleaf to your pom.xml like this:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Then, ensure that you have added the corresponding HTML files as described at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-error-page, like this: 
Lastly, you only need to add a custom controller and implement ErrorController like this:
@Controller
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Object status = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);
        if (status != null) {
            int statusCode = Integer.parseInt(status.toString());
            if (statusCode == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()) {
                return "404";
            } else if (statusCode == HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()) {
                return "500";
            }
        }
        return "error";
    }
}




Hey, thanks for your answer! I've indeed added the Thymeleaf dependency and followed your code, but I'm still not getting my 404 page as intended. Are you adding anything in your application.properties? Thanks!  PS: I also have Spring Security on the application, not sure if that could cause a problem?

No, I haven't added any configurations to application.properties, and I have tested it under Spring Security with normal results. Could you upload your project to Github? It would make troubleshooting much easier for me.

Sure, here is the repo link https://github.com/JoaquinMorenoCode/spring-filemanager-app.git ty!

Just delete the ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.java file in the exception directory.Full path:src/main/java/moreno/joaquin/filemanagerapp/exception/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.java

Great! Thank you so much, do you know when should I be using ResponseEntityExceptionHandler? is it only for rest api?

Yes, ResponseEntityExceptionHandler is specifically designed for REST APIs. However, I typically don't use ResponseEntityExceptionHandler either. Instead, I configure the following:
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true spring.web.resources.add-mappings=false 
This setup causes an exception to be thrown when there is no matching route. Then, I create a global exception handler to catch it and return a JSON response.
